# how to stop overwriting an index number in python list which is already written once?

Tags: python

I have a `list` with index number 0 to 5. I am telling user to input position where they want to mark ('X') into the list and then printing the list each time the user input's a index number. I want the user to input only once in a index number of the list and if user try to overwrite the written value in a list I want to give a message to user as a input 'you can't go there please try again in different position'. I want to keep running the input until the user enters a value in non-written position in the list.

I tried to do it in OOP as I am practicing OOP. I make a board then display the board with print_Board() method. In method input_Value() I tried to make it run under a while loop and break the loop when all positions are filled... also used a try catch error... which will check if the input value must have the index number from 1 to 6 only.

```
class Overwrite:

    list = ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']

    def print_Board(self):
        print(self.list[0:3])
        print(self.list[3:6])

    def input_Value(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.position = input('enter a number between 1 to 6:')     # input a value
                if self.position not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']: # checking if the number is in range(1 to 6) or not
                    print('please try again a number between 1 to 6')
                    continue
                self.position = int(self.position) - 1  # putting -1 so that user input is different than
                self.list[self.position] = 'X'
                self.print_Board()
            except IndexError:
                print('please try again a number between 1 to 6:')
            except ValueError:
                print('please try again a number between 1 to 6:')
            else:
                if '.' not in self.list:  # it will stop the program when all the positions are filled
                    break

    def gameplay(self):
        self.print_Board()
        self.input_Value()
```

Comment: btw Don't use `list` as a variable name, even in a class. This could get confusing.

Comment: Thank u so much... you are right, I will be carefull next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that I can think to do this is to include another selection statement:

```
if self.list[self.position] == 'X':
    print("you can't go there please try again in different position")
    continue
```

This will check if the selected index was already mutated to 'X', if it has, it will restart the while loop. Otherwise, it will continue through your code to change the position to 'X'

Although for general practice, be careful of using pythons keywords as variable names (`self.list`)

Comment: Your `print` statement won't execute correctly, escape the apostrophe with a backslash

Comment: Thank you, it was a typo when I wrote it, corrected now

Answer (score 1):

Check if that list element is already equal to `X`, and if so, print a message and continue the input loop.

```
self.position = int(self.position) - 1
if self.list[self.position] == 'X':
    print('you already entered that position, please try again')
    continue
else:
    self.list[self.position] = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new list class with a different `__setitem__` method.

```py
class ListNoOverwrite(list):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if super().__getitem__(key) == 'X':
            print("Sorry, you can't do that")
            return 1
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
            return 0
```